# Connect to Sql Server of Windows Azure VM from local Sql Server

Tags: azure, sql-server-2012, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to connect to my Sql server 2012 which is setup on **Azure VM**. I am trying to connect it from my local **Sql server 2012**. I have tried all these steps

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-provision-sql-server/

But still not able to connect. I getting this error

[image]

Can Some please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're connecting to cloudnet.app domain address I assume you don't use VPN. This means:
 - SQL Server authentication should be set to mixed mode
 - SQL login should be created or enabled
 - In case enabling SA login make sure you set the password

For connectivity part I agree with Jason's suggestions, but I would not disable firewall, since with endpoints facing public internet it is your last line of defense on the VM. Just make sure you have allow rule for the SQL Server port (most likely 1433).

Answer (score 0):

Confirm the following:

- You have configured the cloud service port 57500 (from the screenshot) to forward to the port that SQL is configured on, typically 1433.
- Turn off the firewall within the VM. Once you get a working connection, I would reconfigure the firewall to only open the port(s) you need for security. The instructions you provided show how to open a specific port, but you should first disable the firewall to rule out a misconfiguration there.
- Remote into the VM and ensure that you're able to use the management tools on that machine to make a local connection. This will help rule firewalls and the load balancer for the cloud service.